# multiple OPTIONAL MATCH in Neo4j 2.2.3 errors

Tags: neo4j, match, cypher, option-type

multiple OPTIONAL MATCH returning the below error in Neo4j 2.2.3. I am using Cypher 2.2 parser.
**

> "org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: null at
>   NullPointerException". The same query works perfectly in Neo4j 2.1.7.

**

```
 match (user:user)-[k:SUBSCRIBED]->(package) 
 where package.startDate < 1439268888365 and package.endDate > 1439268888365 
 with package,user optional match (package)-[j:HAS]->(products) 
 with package,j,products,user optional match (package)-[j:HAS]-(otherpackages) 
 return distinct package,products,user,otherpackages
```

Any pointers to solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-optional-match.html) optional match can return null, to know where the null is returned, simply try every segment of your query with replacing every "with" by a return.

You can also manage null return using a [Case expression](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-expressions.html#query-syntax-case) and replace it by a default value (like 0).

You should consider upgrading to 2.2.4 too, it's a critical update and it will maybe fix your problem just by applying it.

Comment: I realized after few attempts that i am using Cypher parser 2.2 and looks like it isnt supporting the multiple OPTIONAL MATCH. When i switched to 2.1 parser, it went through.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```html
match (user:user)-[k:SUBSCRIBED]->(package:package) 
where package.startDate < 1439268888365 and package.endDate > 1439268888365 
with package,user 
optional match (package)-[j:HAS]->(products:products) with package,j,products,user 
optional match (package)-[j:HAS]-(otherpackages) with package,j,products,user,otherpackages
return 
{
package:[{package:package}],
products:[{products:products}],
user:[{user:user}],
otherpackages:[{otherpackages:otherpackages}]
}
```

In case if you want distinct means use

collect(package)